# Using ZF2 Event manager to save a model

Tags: php, object-oriented, php5, zend-framework

I have been reading about `ZF2 EventManager` for some time now and I wonder what you'd think about this approach.

```
class Model_Member extends App_Model_Model
{
    protected $_data = array(
        'ID' => null,
        'UserName' => null,
        'Password' => null,
        'EmailAddress' => null,
        'CreatedOn' => null,
        'Status' => 0,
        'PasswordResetHash' => null,
        'Role' => 'member'
    );
    const EVENT_SAVE = 'save';
    const EVENT_POSTSAVE = 'post.save';
    public function init()
    {
        $this->events()->attach(self::EVENT_SAVE, array('Service_Member', 'save'));
    }
    public function save()
    {
        $id = $this->events()->trigger(self::EVENT_SAVE, $this)->last();
        $this->ID = $id;
        $this->events()->trigger(self::EVENT_POSTSAVE, $this);
    }
}
```

And of course there is Service_Member

```
public function save($event)
{
    // Get the member from the event
    $member = $event->getTarget();
    // If there is no id, save, otherwise update
    if (!$member->ID) {
        $id = $this->doSave($member);
        $event->setParam('id', $id);
        return $id;
    } else {
        return $this->doUpdate($member);
    }
}
public function doSave(Model_Member $member)
{
    // Check if username is taken
    if ($this->checkIfExists('UserName', $member->UserName)) {
        throw new App_Exception_UserNameExists('This username is already taken.');
    }

    // Check if email address already registered
    if ($this->checkIfExists('EmailAddress', $member->EmailAddress)) {
        throw new App_Exception_EmailAddressExists('This email is already registered.');
    }

    // Set default values
    $member->CreatedOn = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // Encrypt password
    $member->Password = sha1($member->Password);

    // Get the data and save. Return the member with new ID
    $data = $member->_toArray();
    unset($data['ID']);
    $this->getWriteDb()->insert('members', $data);
    $id = $this->getWriteDb()->lastInsertId();
    return $id;
}
```

Do you think this is an acceptable approach?

Comment: I think I chose a very bad time for asking a question? is everyone on holiday :)

Comment: Back from holiday :) I think your code is just fine, don't see anything wrong with it. There is no point in some of your comments, like `// Check if username is taken` when the condition is `($this->checkIfExists('UserName', $member->UserName))` - It's pretty obvious what you do, no need to write a comment about it. Same with `// Encrypt password`, `// Get the member from the event` etc. But if those are helpful to you, leave them as is.

Comment: Hi Yannis, thanks for the reply. The comments were place holders. I put them before I write the code.

My question was is it a good practice to use EventManager to persist models.

Comment: Yeah, I do that a lot :) Beware of [comment smell](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1/comments-are-a-code-smell).

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used PHP recently, just a few, mostly minor notes:

1. > ```
   > // Encrypt password
   > $member->Password = sha1($member->Password);
   > ```

   You might want to use [a salt](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1776/8221) here to make your hashing stronger.
2. > ```
   > $this->getWriteDb()->insert('members', $data);
   > $id = $this->getWriteDb()->lastInsertId();
   > ```

   If that's possible, `insert` could return the ID. It would eliminate temporal coupling (users can't call the methods in the wrong order).

   (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G31: Hidden Temporal Couplings*, p302)
3. > ```
   > 'Status' => 0,
   > ```

   `0` is a magic number here. What could it mean? A named constants would express the intent.
4. These comments are rather redundant, the code is clear and says the same:

   > ```
   > // Check if username is taken
   > if ($this->checkIfExists('UserName', $member->UserName)) {
   >     throw new App_Exception_UserNameExists('This username is already taken.');
   > }
   >
   > // Check if email address already registered
   > if ($this->checkIfExists('EmailAddress', $member->EmailAddress)) {
   >     throw new App_Exception_EmailAddressExists('This email is already registered.');
   > }
   > ```

   ...

   > ```
   > // Get the member from the event
   > $member = $event->getTarget();
   > ```

   (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *Redundant Comments*, p60)
5. Btw, are you sure that you need two different type of exceptions here? Wouldn't be the same exception type with different messages enough?
6. Use `private` instead of `protected` if possible:

   > ```
   > protected $_data = array(
   > ```

   [Should I always use the private access modifier for class fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484845/should-i-always-use-the-private-access-modifier-for-class-fields); *Item 13* of *Effective Java 2nd Edition*: *Minimize the accessibility of classes and members*.
7. > ```
   > class Model_Member extends App_Model_Model
   > ```

   The class name is weird a little bit. Model of a model? `App` also too generic, something more descriptive would be better.
8. > ```
   > $member->CreatedOn = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   > ```

   Wouldn't be better using [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects here?